# Pointer specification

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and have a few basic questions; I read some tutorials and looked at several questions, but I am still a little confused due to some of the wording.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
}
```

Lets say I compile and run the file: `./test blah blah`

To my understanding, `argv[1]` points to a pointer to `blah`; if I need to access the letters in blah, how exactly should I do it?

I tried: `printf("%s\n", argv[1][1])` and `char *pointer = argv[1]` but neither worked.

Did I misunderstand a concept? Or did I just not get the coding part right.

Comment: `int main(char **argv){` --> `int main(int argc, char **argv){` At least that is what the runtime assumes when it calls your `main()`

Comment: Oh ya, thats what I have in my code I just shortened it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value at `argv[1][1]` has type `char` (since `argv` has type `char **`) so you should use the [`%c` (unsigned character) printf format](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

```
printf("%c\n", argv[1][0]); // => b
printf("%c\n", argv[1][1]); // => l
printf("%c\n", argv[1][2]); // => a
printf("%c\n", argv[1][3]); // => h
```

Comment: oh, and `argv[1]` is the first argument because `argv[0]` contains the command. So `argv[1][0]` is the first char of the first argument.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency: yup, and `argv[0][0]` would be `.`, `argv[0][1]` is `/`, etc.

Comment: Lets say I need to create a pointer that points to the end of the string, how do I do it? I think I need to do a linear search for 0 biytebut I am not sure how to implement it

Comment: @NickGong: you can set a pointer to the first character of the string and then increment it until it points to 0 (or `\0`).